# How to make customized middleware in CKAN

Tags: python, flask, ckan

I've met a scenario which I have to override a common middleware in CKAN. And in CKAN default `plugins/interface.py`:

```
class IMiddleware(Interface):
    u'''Hook into CKAN middleware stack
    Note that methods on this interface will be called two times,
    one for the Pylons stack and one for the Flask stack (eventually
    there will be only the Flask stack).
    '''
    def make_middleware(self, app, config):
        u'''Return an app configured with this middleware
        When called on the Flask stack, this method will get the actual Flask
        app so plugins wanting to install Flask extensions can do it like
        this::
            import ckan.plugins as p
            from flask_mail import Mail
            class MyPlugin(p.SingletonPlugin):
                p.implements(p.I18nMiddleware)
                def make_middleware(app, config):
                    mail = Mail(app)
                    return app
        '''
        return app
```

It shows that I have to define "MyMiddleWare" class under a plugin that I want to implement in an extension. However, as it shows in the example, the actual middleware `Mail` is imported from a different class. I want to override `TrackingMiddleware` especially the `__call__(self, environ, start_response)` method, which `environ` and `start_response` are passed in when `make_pylons_stack` are invoked during the configuration phase. If I want to override `TrackingMiddleware` Should I create another `config/middleware/myTrackingMiddleware.py` under `ckanext-myext/` and then in `plugin.py` I implement the following?:

```
from myTrackingMiddleware import MyTrackingMiddleware

class MyPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IMiddleware, inherit=True)

    def make_middleware(self, app, config):
        tracking = MytrackingMiddleware(app, config)
        return app
```

**Update:**

I tried to make the `myTrackingMiddleware` in an hierarchy and imported it in `plugin.py`, but I didn't received any request to `'/_tracking'` in `myTrackingMiddleware`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a set of process, and it works for myself. Basically, I kept what I have done as what I have mentioned in my own question. Then, if your middleware has some conflict with CKAN default Middleware, you probably have to completely disable the default one. I discussed with some major contributors of CKAN here: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4451. After I disabled CKAN `ckan.tracking_enabled` in `dev.ini`, I have the flexibility to get values from `environ` and handle tracking with my customized logic.